# Shorthand syntax for "named parameters" in Typescript

Tags: typescript

TLDR:

Can you merge declaring the type of a function parameter and destructuring it?

```
const greet = ({ name: string, age: number, likesCoffee: boolean }) => `...`
greet({ name: 'Joe', age: 37, likesCoffee: true });
```

---

Assume I have a functions with a lot of parameters like this:

```
const greet = (name: string, age: number, likesCoffee: boolean) => `Hi, ${name}! It seems you ${likesCoffee ? 'like' : 'do not like'} coffee and are ${age} years old.`
greet('Joe', 37, true);
```

Seeing this call, I really don't know what the arguments mean, so I refactor it to use [parameter destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#parameter-destructuring):

```
const greet = ({ name, age, likesCoffee }: { name: string, age: number, likesCoffee: boolean }) => `Hi, ${name}! It seems you ${likesCoffee ? 'like' : 'do not like'} coffee and are ${age} years old.`
greet({ name: 'Joe', age: 37, likesCoffee: true });
```

Now I like it a lot more!

But I often find myself declaring the type of the parameters for one function only and immediately destructuring. So I'd like to have some shorthand syntax like this:

```
const greet = ({ name: string, age: number, likesCoffee: boolean }) => `Hi, ${name}! It seems you ${likesCoffee ? 'like' : 'do not like'} coffee and are ${age} years old.`
greet({ name: 'Joe', age: 37, likesCoffee: true });
```

Is there a proposal for this kind of syntax?

Comment: _"Is there a proposal for this kind of syntax?"_... no, because it doesn't make sense. The function parameter cannot be a type definition

Comment: the topic is complicated, because the `::` syntax may also clash with JS https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator Even if that particular proposal seems inactive JS is still evolving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#29526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526) asking for some sort of shorthand type annotations for binding patterns.  If you want to see this happen it couldn't hurt to give it a .  It probably won't *help* much, either, but it's at least something.

Note that the "obvious" syntax won't work because it already has a runtime effect of renaming variables  For example, `({x: string})=>{}` will copy the `x` property of the input to a new variable named `string`.  The issue suggests possibly using something like `({x::string})=>{}`  but the particular syntax is probably off-topic here.

Recently the TS team started a series of *feature updates*, see [microsoft/TypeScript#54923](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54923), where older feature request with lots of upvotes will be linked to new issues, to give information on the current state of the request and to moderate the discussion to be as constructive as possible.  Right now microsoft/TypeScript#29526 seems to be approximately the 60th most upvoted issue, meaning it could be a few years before it is updated (looks like they are aiming to update about 5 issues every release, which happen every few months, so, uh, yeah).